# Python dataframe difference between this row and fifth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe. I have timestamp index. I want to compute five minutes difference in data. Each row is a one minute data. Basically, I want to compute difference between this row and last fifth row.

My code:

```
df = 

TIMESTAMP                               A                    
2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00          78.080002
2015-01-01 09:51:00-05:00          78.809998
2015-01-01 09:52:00-05:00          79.500000
2015-01-01 09:53:00-05:00          80.099998
2015-01-01 10:07:00-05:00          88.699997
2015-01-01 10:08:00-05:00          89.099998
2015-01-01 10:09:00-05:00          89.599998
2015-01-01 10:10:00-05:00          90.199997
2015-01-01 10:11:00-05:00          90.699997

df['A_dif'] = df['A'].diff()
```

Present output:

```
print(df['A_dif'])

TIMESTAMP                      A_dif
2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00         NaN
2015-01-01 09:51:00-05:00    0.729996
2015-01-01 09:52:00-05:00    0.690002
2015-01-01 09:53:00-05:00    0.599998
2015-01-01 10:07:00-05:00    8.599998
2015-01-01 10:08:00-05:00    0.400002
2015-01-01 10:09:00-05:00    0.500000
2015-01-01 10:10:00-05:00    0.599998
2015-01-01 10:11:00-05:00    0.500000
2015-01-01 10:12:00-05:00    0.400002
```

Expected output:

```
TIMESTAMP                         A_dif
2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00         NaN
2015-01-01 09:51:00-05:00         NaN
2015-01-01 09:52:00-05:00         NaN
2015-01-01 09:53:00-05:00         NaN
2015-01-01 10:07:00-05:00        10.61
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pass `periods`

```
df.A.diff(periods = 4)
TIMESTAMP
2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00          NaN
2015-01-01 09:51:00-05:00          NaN
2015-01-01 09:52:00-05:00          NaN
2015-01-01 09:53:00-05:00          NaN
2015-01-01 10:07:00-05:00    10.619995
2015-01-01 10:08:00-05:00    10.290000
2015-01-01 10:09:00-05:00    10.099998
2015-01-01 10:10:00-05:00    10.099999
2015-01-01 10:11:00-05:00     2.000000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great. It worked. Similarly, how do I compute % difference between this row and fifth row? I mean `(row5-row1)*100/row1`

Comment: @Mainland `df.A.pct_change(periods=4)
`

Comment: @Mainland YW : -) happy coding

Comment: Happy coding. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Spark SQl:

```
select timestamp, A ,A-lag(_c3,4)over(order by _c3) from your table
```

4  in lag will how to rows to get the value down, once you have got lag of the  row to subtract it